# On the definition of eigenframe

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, epr-spectroscopy

While reading the following article,

- Elizaveta A. Suturina, Kevin Mason, Carlos F. G. C. Geraldes, Ilya Kuprov, David Parker, [Beyond Bleaney's theory: experimental and theoretical analysis of periodic trends in lanthanide-induced chemical shift](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201706931), Angewandte Chemie, September 25, 2017

I came across the term *eigenframe*, which I am unfamiliar with. **What is an *eigenframe*?**

Here is the context in which it was used:

> In particular, pseudo contact chemical shifts (PCS) induced by lanthanide complexes are commonly described by McConnell's long-range relation (SI units),
> $$ \delta^{PCS} = \frac{1}{12\pi r^3}[\chi_{ax}(3\cos^2 \theta -1)+3\chi_{rh}\sin^2\theta \cos2\phi]$$
> where $\theta, \phi, r$ are the polar coordinates of the nucleus relative to the lanthanide in the ***eigenframe*** of the molar magnetic susceptibility tensor, and $\chi_{ax}$ and $\chi_{rh}$ are axiality and rhombicity of the susceptibility tensor.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything definitive but both

https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=4172326

and

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/eigenframe-definition-please.876035/

suggest that an *eigenframe* is the basis formed by the eigenvectors of the relevant operator, the molar magnetic susceptibility tensor in this case.